# Angular strange behavior in production mode

Tags: angular, angular8, document-body

When I'm building my project in production mode `ng build --prod --output-path=../Angular --base-href=/autopoint/ --deploy-url=/autopoint/Angular/`, a strange line at the top of the html before the  tag appears but when I'm running it with an ng serve, it is gone. Any ideas what this might be caused by?

*_Layout.cshtml*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AutoPoint</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,600,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    @Styles.Render("~/Angular/Styles")
</head>
<body id="app">

@RenderBody()


    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' type='module'></script>", "~/Angular/Scripts")
    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' nomodule defer></script>", "~/Angular/ScriptsIE")
</body>
</html>
```

*Index.cshtml*

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [BOM Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom) this link might help you... if you are using vs code for build it might save BOM characters also, so you can change settings, to avoid them.

Comment: Tried to save the *_Layout.cshtml* file without BOM because I thought the problem might be in the @RenderBody(), the whitespace is moving with it no matter where I put it, but it didn't help at all.

Comment: Don't know if that solved your problem, but give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601957/strange-whitespace-appearing-in-mvc4-razor-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. Invisible whitespace character.
[image]